# Significato di "cappelli alla ladra"

Tags: meaning

Nella prefazione a *Nostro lunedí* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> Da tutte le parti li vedevamo avanzare fra la sabbia sollevata dal vento e a chi restò in piedi non rimase che sperare che si trattasse veramente di Inglesi. Ma gli Inglesi portano ridicoli elmetti rotondi. Fra la sabbia distinguemmo soltanto enormi **cappelli alla ladra**. Ci vennero addosso gli Australiani di Freiberg. Difficile riuscire a scordarli del tutto, chi li ha incontrati in quei giorni laggiú.

Questa scena ha luogo a El Alamein durante la seconda guerra mondiale.

Ho cercato "ladro" e "ladra" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire cosa sono i "cappelli alla ladra". Suppongo che siano i [cappelli dell'esercito australiano](http://www.collezioni-f.it/biagi/biagi021.jpg) durante la seconda guerra mondiale, ma non so perché vengano chiamati "alla ladra". Qualcuno di voi me lo potrebbe spiegare?

Comment: Sarà una foggia di cappello tipicamente in uso presso i ladri :) ma non ho idea di quale possa essere. si può solo intuire che sono grandi.
Mi vengono in mente i cappelli da briganti (tipo: http://www.lospeaker.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/cappello-da-brigante.jpg) ma probabilmente mi sbaglio. Dov'è ambientata la scena?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: La scena ha luogo a El Alamein durante la seconda guerra mondiale.

Comment: Purtoppo come dicevo, non so come possa essere un cappello "da ladro"; si può dedurre secondo me che abbia la tesa molto larga per tenere il viso in ombra (rende difficile l'identificazione) ma, in questo caso, per proteggersi dal sole.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Suppongo che siano i [cappelli dell'esercito australiano](http://www.collezioni-f.it/biagi/biagi021.jpg) durante la seconda guerra mondiale, ma non so perché vengano chiamati "alla ladra".

Comment: Ho trovato anche questa illustrazione https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Light_horse_walers.jpg il cappello dell'uomo sulla destra è a cono e con la tesa un po' floscia. Potrebbe ricordare quello "da brigante" es. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Brigand_costume_latium_1820.jpg/290px-Brigand_costume_latium_1820.jpg
È solo una supposizione ma è la migliore che ho.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi:  È un'ipotesi che ha senso. Ho trovato anche [questo disegno](http://www.diggerhistory.info/images/thru-ages/ww2-3.jpg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'espressione significa con tutta probabilità *"cappelli di foggia simile a quelli usati dai ladri"*. Non ci sono molte indicazioni su che aspetto possano avere.

La scena è ambientata ad El Alamein durante la seconda guerra mondiale; cercando alcune illustrazioni delle uniformi australiane di quel periodo 
[1](http://www.collezioni-f.it/biagi/biagi021.jpg) [2](http://www.diggerhistory.info/images/thru-ages/ww2-3.jpg) [3](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Light_horse_walers.jpg) si può dedurre che abbiano almeno alcune di queste caratteristiche:

- tesa larga (per ripararsi dal sole, la cosa è coerente con l'aggettivo *"enormi"*)
- tesa un po' floscia
- probabilmente a punta

Le caratteristiche possono ricordare un cappello *"da brigante"* come questi: [4](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/Ritratto_di_A._Gasparone_e_sua_moglie_Geltrude.jpg/220px-Ritratto_di_A._Gasparone_e_sua_moglie_Geltrude.jpg) [5](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Brigand_costume_latium_1820.jpg/290px-Brigand_costume_latium_1820.jpg)

La caratteristica della tesa ampia è anche coerente con l'utilizzo "da ladro" del cappello in quanto un cappello, appunto, "da ladro" deve tenere il viso in ombra per rendere più difficile l'identificazione.